# php xpath using identifier tag as a title?

Tags: php, xpath, echo

I'm trying to learn how to curl/scrape and echo text with php pretty well. So far I've learned how to do it with tags like  and unique divs. For ex, below successfully scrapes and echos text using the div class"market"

```
<?php 

$doc = new DOMDocument;

// We don't want to bother with white spaces
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

// Most HTML Developers are chimps and produce invalid markup...
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;

$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.nbcnews.com/business');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query = "//div[@class='market']";

$entries = $xpath->query($query);
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
echo trim($entry->textContent);  // use `trim` to eliminate spaces
}
```

However, I'd like to expand that ability to get even more precise, for example in the below situation, where the a class and various div tags are used many times throughout that website, and the only unique aspect of the below code is that it's using different titles, which in this case is "10-year yield." Is it possible to adjust the existing php code I'm using, to scrape using a title identifier? Otherwise, I'm not sure how to grab something like this, without grabbing everything else using similar tags. Thank you for any thoughts! (in the below case I'm trying to echo the "2.20%"

```
    <!-- BEGIN: Quote -->
    <li class="row">
    <a class="quote" href="/data/bonds/index.html">
        <span class="column quote-name" title="10-year yield">10-year 
    yield</span>
        <span class="column quote-col"><span class="pre-currency-symbol">
   </span><span stream="last_572094" class="quote-dollar" title="10-year 
   yield">2.20</span><span class="post-currency-symbol">%</span></span>
        <span  stream="changePct_572094" class="column quote-change"><span 
   class="posData">+0.00</span></span>
    </a>
    </li>
   <!-- END: Quote -->
```

Comment: Have your tried a loop using `$query = "//span[@title='10-year yield']";`? Assuming it should always have the  class `quote-dollar` can also help as you can check the dom entry for the class.

Comment: hm, not sure how to make that work in the existing code, but I see the logic there.